# js - using replace method to replace html element

Tags: javascript, html, methods, replace

I have a question. I have a work this morning but i don't know how to do it.
My work here (html):

```
<div class="demo">
    <p>this is demo text</p>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var tempdata = $(".demo").text();
var replacedata = tempdata.replace("text","<span>1234</span>");
```

Look everything ok. But result is: `this is demo <span>1234</span>`. This isn't my result I want. How to make  in this string become a HTMLelement by using replace method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the value back, use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) so it won't encode it, like this:

```
var tempdata = $(".demo").text();
var replacedata = tempdata.replace("text","<span>1234</span>");
$(".demo").html(replacedata);​​​​​​
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zy6vD/)

Also, you can pass a method to [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you're doing this to many elements, like this:

```
$(".demo").html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace("text","<span>1234</span>");
});​
```

Note this uses `.html()` as the source as well, but makes no difference for the example code.

[You can see a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BnYN/1/)

Comment: Hi Nick! html(function(i, h) - what does the "i" stand for?

Comment: @ming - It gets 2 arguments, the first is the index, the second is the current `.html()` value :)

Comment: I see! I tried: $("textarea").html(function(i,h){console.log(h)}). I see it iterates through all the elements, allowing me to apply for function for it. thanks a tonne for helping me understand this. Can i use this technique for all functions?

Comment: @ming - since jQuery 1.4+, yes *most* functions will accept a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('demo').firstElementChild.innerHTML =
  document.getElementById('demo').firstElementChild.innerHTML.replace(/text/, "<span>1234</span>");
```